# Woocommerce - Specific template for product category?

Tags: plugins

I'd like to create a specific template for specific category (not for single product).

Is it possible and how to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create  specific template for specific category using taxonomy-product_cat.php template.

For more information visit [this page](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

Comment: Thanks for fast response

I've also found the answer as you mentioned. Let me describe for more detail.

We can override it by creating our own template with the format
taxonomy-product_cat-{slug}.php

e.g. if our category is named 'abc product', go to check the url we'll see it display as abc-product.

Then our template should be named as taxonomy-product_cat-abc-product.php

Comment: I had the same problem and after searching hard I found this plugin. Hope it can help.
http://magnigenie.com/product/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-category-pages/

Comment: \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\taxonomy-product_cat.php copy into \wp-content\themes\MYTHEME\woocommerce\taxonomy-product_cat.php