# Custom Pages for Woocommerce Product-Category Pages

Tags: plugins, categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm looking to create unique pages for each product-category I have in woocommerce.

There are 5 main categories, each having a few sub-categories. The idea is to make each main category a unique landing page that speaks specifically to that product category.

In wordpress, I understand there is the ability to do this by placing category-slug.php files in your theme directory. However, I am unsure how to do this with woocommerce and its product-categories.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This question was already answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95386/woocommerce-specific-template-for-product-category), also keep in mind that WooCommerce has their own [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)/support.

Answer (score -1):

l think that the best strategy ia to to do it with shortcode by using the plugin Visual Composer.

Then you have to built the product category, then the pages and then to retrieve and display with a shortcode the product category to every page respectively.

Visual composer is a premium plugin but it worth its money.

The usual shortcode has the following form:

> [product_category category="category-slug" per_page="24" columns="3"]

Kind Regards

John Divramis